# Dropdownlist selected value are reset after postback

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am very new to asp.net and I have some code to fix for dropdownlist. After the user is hitting the search button, the selected values are getting reset. Would you please help me with this?

This is the design page

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Search</legend>

            <table class="tblsearch">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:80px">Category:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistMainCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdmaincat" DataTextField="MainCategory" DataValueField="MainCategoryId" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdmaincat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Tbl_MainCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                    <td>Sevices:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistCat" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdcat" DataTextField="Category" DataValueField="CategoryId">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdcat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryId], [Category] FROM [Tbl_Category] WHERE ([MainCategoryRef] = @MainCategoryRef)">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDlistMainCat" Name="MainCategoryRef" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
   </fieldset> 
   <fieldset>

   <table class="tblsearch">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:80px">Nationality:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistNat" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdnat" DataTextField="Nationality" DataValueField="NationalityId" EnableViewState="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdnat" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Nationality]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                     </td>
                </tr>



          <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistAge" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdage" DataTextField="Age" DataValueField="AgeV">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdage" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [AgeV], [Age] FROM [Tbl_Age]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Experience:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistExp" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdexp" DataTextField="Exp" DataValueField="ExpV">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdexp" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ExpV], [Exp] FROM [Tbl_Exp]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
                     </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlistGen" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" class="btn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="BtnSearch_Click" />
                       </td>
                </tr>
            </table>



</fieldset>
```

and this is the action

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ClientId"] == null)
        {
            MyAccBox.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MyAccBox.Visible = true;
            lblfullname.Text = Session["Fullname"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("View.aspx?cat=" + DDlistCat.SelectedValue + "&nat=" + DDlistNat.SelectedValue + "&age=" + DDlistAge.SelectedValue + "&exp=" + DDlistExp.SelectedValue + "&gen=" + DDlistGen.SelectedValue + "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled in the form?I mean add `EnableViewState=true` to your dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would not occur had you bind the dropdown from code behind in `!IsPostBack` .

```
if(!IsPostBack)   
{
DDlistExp.DataSource = DataSet.Tables[0];    
DDlistExp.DataValueField = "ExpV";
DDlistExp.DataTextField = "Exp";
DDlistExp.DataBind();    
}
```

Comment: i haveto add this condition on page_load ?

Comment: i tried your solution but its not working on page_load action, the design page above is on the master page , so each time the page refresh the value are getting populated into dropdownlist. i tried something like ddlistcat.selectedvalue = session["ddlistcat"]; but not working

Comment: Write code on master page codebehind and set the selected value there after dropdown bind,

Comment: thank you neel , i will keep the data population on code behind under condition if (!postback) and will let you know